# What is xmmword in IDA Pro?

Tags: ida, disassembly, assembly

*Probably a silly question.*

[image]

What's the xmmword means in IDA Pro?

Answer (score 3):

`XMMWORD` is a 128-bit operand for SSE (previously MMX) instructions (it is nothing special in IDA Pro).

It is derived from names of XMM registers (`XMM0`, `XMM1`, ...) used with SSE instructions.

- **SSE** means “**S**treaming **S**IMD **E**xtensions”, where
- **SIMD** means “**S**ingle **I**nstruction **M**ultiple **D**ata”.

  (**S**ingle **I**nstruction - for example addition – is performed on **M**ultiple **D**ata - for example on multiple pairs of numbers.)

(**SSE** = **SIMD** + Floating Point Arithmetic + Saturation Arithmetic + Special Instructions)

For explanation:

- Beside “basic”, well-known instructions (e.g. `ADD` or `JMP`) inherited from early Intel X86 instruction set, there is *other* instruction set (containing e.g. `MAXPS` or `MOVNTQ` instructions):

  - **SSE** (previously **MMX** – officially a meaningless acronym, often interpreted as **M**ulti**M**edia e**X**tension) with their *own special set of 128-bit registers* (`XMM0`, `XMM1`, ... ),
    further extended to
  - **AVX** (**A**dvanced **V**ector e**X**tensions) with added

    - 256-bit YMM registers (`YMM0`, `YMM1`, ...  – lower halves overlap with XMM registers), and
    - 512-bit ZMM registers (`ZMM0`, `ZMM1`, ...  – lower halves overlap with YMM registers).